# decoding a php array to get a variable

Tags: php, mysql

How do I get `fname` from the result of SQL query and store it in `$_SESSION['fname']`.

```
<?php 
    include('init.php');
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST))
    {
    $loginemail=$_POST["loginemail"];
    $loginpassword=$_POST["loginpassword"];
    $fname="";
    $sql = "select count(*),fname from users where password='$loginpassword' and email='$loginemail'";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if($result){
    $response =array();
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        array_push($response,array("Count"=>$row[0],"name"=>$row[1]));
    }
    $_SESSION["fname"]=$fname;
    echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$response),JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
}
else{
    echo "error";
}
    mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

This is my php code to get the count and fname(username) from database using sql query
init.php has the connection details
my aim here is to retrieve fname using emailid and password 
i get the count which is always 1 as per my database restrictions and a fname i want to declare a session variable as this fname
how do i decode the array to get fname
thanks in advance

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you don't assign a value to $fname

```
<?php 
    include('init.php');
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST))
    {
    $loginemail=$_POST["loginemail"];
    $loginpassword=$_POST["loginpassword"];
    $fname="";
    $sql = "select count(*),fname from users where password='$loginpassword' and email='$loginemail'";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if($result){
    $response =array();
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        array_push($response,array("Count"=>$row[0],"name"=>$row[1]));
        //
        // try assign $fname  here  if you want the first you can 
        // 
        if($fname ==""){
          $fname = $row[1];
        }
        //
    }

    $_SESSION["fname"]=$fname;
    echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$response),JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
}
else{
    echo "error";
}
    mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are making an associative array, you need to access Count and name as keys. Like:

```
foreach($response as $key => $value) {
 echo "Key=" . $key . ", Value=" . $value;
 echo "<br/>";
}
```

But if you are sure that you will always get a single row, why don't you just store them in scalar variables like $count and $fname and inside your code do this:

```
$count; $fname = "";
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $count = $row[0];
    $fname = $row[1];
}
```